# what is the difference between Hibernate.initialize and eager fetching

Tags: hibernate, orm

Why I can't use EAGER fetching for the same purpose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use EAGER fetching to obtain the same result, at the end. But this means things will be **always** eagerly loaded (vs when you just need to). Is this what you want?

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [20.1.4. Initializing collections and proxies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization)

Comment: Does EAGER fetch get the data immediately vs when accessed?

Comment: @user319694 Yes, that's the principle of EAGER (vs LAZY).

Comment: I found it was needed since the session was closed and the data was needed outside. Thanks for the help